# Adding json object to unnamed set of json objections

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have here a set of json objects.

```
[
  {
    "group": "GroupName1",
    "name": "Name1",
    "nick": "Nick1",
    "host": "Hostname1",
    "user": "user1",
    "sshport": "22",
    "httpport": "80"
  },
  {
    "group": "GroupName2",
    "name": "Name2",
    "nick": "Nick2",
    "host": "hostname2",
    "user": "user2",
    "sshport": "22",
    "httpport": "80"
  }

]
```

I have a CLI script taking raw_input and building a new dict object containing the new object parameters as such:

```
def main():
    # CLI Input
    group_in = raw_input("Group: ")
    name_in = raw_input("Name: ")
    nick_in = raw_input("Nick: ")
    host_in = raw_input("Host: ")
    user_in = raw_input("User: ")
    sshport_in = raw_input("SSH Port: ")
    httpport_in = raw_input("HTTP Port: ")

    # New server to add
    jdict = {
        "group": group_in,
        "name": name_in,
        "nick": nick_in,
        "host": host_in,
        "user": user_in,
        "sshport": sshport_in,
        "httpport": httpport_in
    }
```

Assuming json file containing the aforementioned json objects formatted as such is loaded as:

```
with open(JSON_PATH, mode='r') as rf:
    jf = json.load(rf)
```

I know how to do this by hacking the file using readlines/writelines, but how would I add `jdict` in at the end of `jf` pythonically so I can just write the file back with the complete new set of objects formatted in the same way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`jf` is now *just a Python list*, so you can append the new dictionary to your list:

```
jf.append(jdict)
```

then write out the whole object back to your file, replacing the old JSON string:

```
with open(JSON_PATH, mode='w') as wf:
    json.dump(jf, wf)
```

Comment: As usual, I was overcomplicating it in my thought process. Thank you.